# Algorithm to select points from matrix

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

This seems to be a simple problem but I am stuck at this problem. The problem is that I have a matrix of size `X x Y`. There may be some points at (i,j). It is, however, not necessary that all locations (i,j) should have a point (i.e. there are < XY points). How should I can select the biggest subset of these points such that no points in the selected subset has same i (row number) or j (column number)

Comment: Seems like the biggest set you can do is min(X,Y).  One possible set is the diagonal set.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of data and what you would expect? From your description it sounds unlikely that there would be a single biggest subset, so do you want to enumerate all possible subsets of the largest size, or just find any single one?

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more clear!

Comment: Should this be tagged as homework?

Comment: No, this isn't homework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [maximum matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29) problem, which is poly-time solvable. Given an instance of your problem, construct a bipartite graph with nodes a<sub>1</sub>, …, a<sub>X</sub>, b<sub>1</sub>, …, b<sub>Y</sub>, and edges a<sub>i</sub>b<sub>j</sub> for all (i,j) where there's a point. Take the points corresponding to the edges in a maximum matching.

Answer (score 2):

Construct graph. Points are vertices of graph. Every vertice is connected with all vertices in the same row and same column - edges of graph. Your problem is to select **maximum** independent set of vertices (without common edges).

[Independent_set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_%28graph_theory%29)

This problem is equivalent to to maximum clique problem in complement graph, so Bron-Kerbosch algorithm could be used.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem#Finding_maximum_cliques_in_arbitrary_graphs

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_graph

[Bron-Kerbosch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bron%E2%80%93Kerbosch_algorithm)

Comment: Yes, it's independent set in the point-point conflict graph, but this special case is in P (maximum matching).

Comment: @Per Yes, your approach is much simpler